# Summarise multiple means and sd in long format using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm having problems summarizing data into a long format for easier eval in ggplot.

```
data <- data.frame (id  = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
                rep = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
                value1 = sample(1:100, 15, replace=TRUE),
                value2 = sample(1:100, 15, replace=TRUE),
                value3 = sample(1:100, 15, replace=TRUE))
```

Assume this data set. I want to group by id and summarise mean and sd for value1, value2 and value 3 in long format. SD and mean for each id should be in one row

```
library(dplyr)
summary <- data %>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  summarise(mn = mean(value1),
            sd = sd(value1))%>%
  mutate(type = "Value1")%>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  summarise(mn = mean(value2),
            sd = sd(value2))%>%
    mutate(type = "Value2")
```

If I do it like this it will overwrite the values it has calculated before. How do I add them instead of overwriting them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show what your expected output should be for your example?

Comment: Try `data %>%group_by(id) %>% summarise_at(vars(starts_with('value')), list(mean = mean, sd = sd))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you wanted, but since you mentioned `long form`:

```
data <- data.frame (id  = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
                rep = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
                value1 = sample(1:100, 15, replace=TRUE),
                value2 = sample(1:100, 15, replace=TRUE),
                value3 = sample(1:100, 15, replace=TRUE))


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
summary <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(c(-id, -rep), names_to = "type") %>% 
  group_by(id, type)%>%
  summarise(mn = mean(value),
            sd = sd(value))
```

summary is now:

> ```
>       id type      mn    sd
>    <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
>  1     1 value1  39.3 22.1 
>  2     1 value2  27.7 23.0 
>  3     1 value3  15   10.4 
>  4     2 value1  88.7 12.1 
>  5     2 value2  31.7 25.0 
>  6     2 value3  44.7 44.2 
>  7     3 value1  48.7 27.3 
>  8     3 value2  53   36.7 
>  9     3 value3  50.3 10.2 
> 10     4 value1  34   20.2 
> 11     4 value2  44.7 10.7 
> 12     4 value3  21    4.58
> 13     5 value1  59   29.6 
> 14     5 value2  61.7 15.9 
> 15     5 value3  12.3 14.7
> ```